# JQuery: Finding an elements position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was researching through the internet but found nothing, so I decided to ask here. "How to detect which HTML element is positioned in the center of the screen". What I exactly need is to find an element with `right:0.`

It was positioned like this:

```
$("#element").animate({right: 0}, 50);
```

I just have multiple elements moving around on the screen, and on certain time they stop. Others are out of the screen. This one is in and at the center. By the way, it's `width:100%`. Any ideas how can I detect it in `DIV`tag in HTML.

**Note:** I have a `#container` that wraps all elements.

Comment: By the way, I am using jQuery

Comment: @JohnKarver Create jsfiddle of the complete relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you said : `What I exactly need is to find an element with right:0.`

You can do this:

```
 var elements = $('[style=right:0px]');
```

However this will work if your element has a `style` attribute.

Otherwise, you can try something like this:

```
 var elements = $('*').filter(function() {
      return this.element.style['right'] == '0px';
      //or -> return $(this).css('right') == '0px';
 });
```

Comment: I forgot, that I have 2 elements there. Will they be both stored?

Comment: This `[style=right:0px]` won't work if there is more style defined in attribute or even space in property declaration

Comment: @Tushar I guess (and I hope) he meant `you have no idea how great you helped`, sorry for my poor english :)

Comment: Basically, yes.. I've said that I appreciate the the help. Why rude? To whom?

Comment: @JohnKarver honestly, this `You don't even understand` sounds weird :)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers covered the lookup by style attributes, but I'd add an id/class when you do the `.animate()` for easier later retrieval.

```
$(".centered").removeClass("centered"); // optionally, remove the class for the existing center
$("#element").addClass("centered").animate({right: 0}, 50); // mark the new center
// later in the code
var $center = $(".centered");
```

Even better, the *centered* class can be used to style the element according to your needs, so you don't need to animate style, just animate the class.